# Compiler can't find cls files in Windows

Tags: paths, texlive-2020, documentclass

I have TeXLive2014 under Windows10 that was working fine for 6 years. Problems started a week ago or so. I opened a document which compiled in December correctly, made some irrelevant changes (nothing in the preamble) and once tried to compile the following message poped out:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./bisul2021-ib-math14.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.

! LaTeX Error: File `article.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name:
```

The same happened when I tried a minimal example without any additional packages and definitions. No matter if it's article or report, cls files cannot be located. I couldn't find any solution over the Internet, so I decided to get TeXLive 2020, which I downloaded from here: https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html
Instalation took almost 4 hours, system claimed it was a success.
Then I opened a random LaTeX file with the new editor and the result was the same. So I followed the advise from here: https://www.tug.org/texlive/windows.html
It told me to

```
In File Explorer, right-click the texmf-local folder
Choose Properties
Select the Security tab
Click the Advanced button
Click the Change permissions button and deal with the resulting UAC prompt
There is no need to change anything in the box with Permission entries. Instead:
Check the checkbox 'Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object'
Finally, click the OK button and click Yes in the resulting Windows Security dialog.
```

And now the result is that the new tex editor doesn't open at all, and when I open any latex file with the old one, still get the same problem, cls files are not found.

Comment: What is your TeX editor?

Comment: @Bernard Texworks

Comment: Was it installed with TeX Live 2020?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, I got the old one connected to texlive2014 and the new one

Comment: TeX Live 2014? Really?

Comment: Maybe uninstall TeX Live 2014 if you didn't.

Comment: close the editor for now and try to compile on a command line.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Yes, both 2014 and 2020 are there

Comment: Ok, using TeXLive 2014 manager I updated the database which solved the problem with 2014, the files compile the way they should. Still, it would be nice if 2020 release worked...